# How to create Ul list from string?

Tags: php, jquery, html

i prefer jquery.

let's say i have a string with ,

adam, lisa, john, sarah

and i want to turn them into :

`<ul><li>Adam</li><li>lisa</li><li>john</li><li>sarah</li></ul>`

Comment: please clarify question, you want this output to the page? is jQuery handling this string? Or is PHP doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"<ul><li>" + "adam, lisa, john, sarah".split(", ").join("</li><li>") + "</li></ul>"
```

**[Edit:]** I assumed javascript since you mentioned jQuery. I don't know the best way to do it in php, but you do the same as above using `preg_split` and `implode` in php.

Comment: how to implement it in html/php file?

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery's [$.map](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.map) function:

```
var names = 'adam,lisa,john,sarah';
var html = '<ul>'+$.map(names.split(','), function(name){
    return '<li>'+name+'</li>'
}).join('')+'</ul>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could do explode and foreach:

```
$array = explode(', ','adam, lisa, john, sarah');
foreach ($array as $name) {
  $output .= '<li>' . $name . '</li>';
}
echo '<ul>' . $output . '</ul>';
```

Maybe a little simpler.

EDIT: Even easier would be a regular str_replace.

```
$list = '<ul><li>' . str_replace(', ','</li><li>','adam, lisa, john, sarah') . '</li></ul>';
echo $list;
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it in PHP, explode the string to make it into an array and then use array_map to convert each item to a li tag. Once that's done, implode it to get the desired result:

```
$items = explode( ",", "adam,lisa,john,sarah" );

array_map( "makeLiTag", $items );

echo( "<ul>" . implode( "", $items ) . "</ul>" );

function makeLiTag( &$item, $key )
{
    $item = "<li>$item</li>";
}
```

Comment: I think you may need to put the callback function as the first argument?

array_map('makeLiTag', $items);